# Simple Next and Previous Show and Hide with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagination, show-hide

I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to show and hide a series of divs with Previous and Next buttons by adding and removing some classes.

So far, I can get the Next button to trigger, but it's adding the `active` class to all of the divs and not just the next one in line.

I've been reading through other examples and so far they seem really bloated or not what I am looking for specifically.

Here's what I have so far:

**Codepen Link:** https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/pxrrmy/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="item active">
    <h2>Thing One</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Thing Two</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Thing Three</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btns">
  <a href="#" class="btn prev">Previous</a>
  <a class="btn next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.next').on("click", function(){
  if($('.item').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.item').next().addClass('active');

  }
})
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
.active {
  display:block !important;
}

.item {
  display:none;
}
```

It seems like this should be fairly simple, but I can't seem to think of how to target the next div by itself without it showing all of the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should get your last active element and activate next after it:

```
$('.next').on("click", function(){
  const $active = $('.item.active');
  const $next = $active.next();

  if ($next.length) {
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $next.addClass('active');
  }
})
```

The problem in your current code is that you are getting all items and performing `hasClass` on all of them so it returns true all the time because there is at least one element with this class and then you are getting next element after each item element and add `active` class to them so all of your elements are activated in result.

Comment: This works by showing the next div, but doesn't remove the previous class.

Comment: Thanks! Now if I can figure out how to get it to stop removing the class when it reaches the end, it'd be great!

Comment: EPIC! Thanks! This makes sense now. Using length to pass the check is WAY easier than the route I was trying, lol! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
$('a.next').on("click", function(){
  var a = $('.item.active').last();
  a.next().addClass('active');
  a.removeClass('active')
});
```

Comment: Sweet, this works!
But do you know how to get it to stop removing the class if it hit the last div? Other wise if someone clicks the next button again, it will remove the class and blank everything out.

Comment: Am... I think is validating if( $('.item:last').hasClass('active') )

Comment: Hmmm, ok. Yeah, I'm trying to test it out with some other logic and it's getting messy. I would think it would be easy to check to see if it's on the last element then stop with removing the class.